# controller has no segue with identifier error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I get this error when going to a uitableview and seeing its detailsview. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'lmDetails''

I have two tabbars the expection happens if I call the tabbar 2 that contains a uitableview this will open up uitableview 1 if a button is clicked. The error shows up when going from uitableview 1 to its details view. In uitableview 2 I call uitableview1 to show up using the following segue:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"seguelmResults"]) {
        LMResultsTableViewController *cvc = (LMResultsTableViewController *)[segue  destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = sender;
        HolidayChartListItem *obj=[[HolidayChartListItem alloc]init];
        obj= [totalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cvc.selDestinationId = obj.DestinationId;
        cvc.selCountryId = obj.CountryId;
}
```

If I open up uitableview 1 from tabbar 1 - and not from uitableview 2 then there are no errors when going to the details page.

Comment: identifier 'lmDetails'' is not listed in the example you provided. Are you sure it exists or is that a typo? It sounds like the segue you setup is lmDetails and not seguelmResults as in the example you provided.

Comment: Like the error states *Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'lmDetails'*. Check your storyboard segues identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the segue you setup is "lmDetails" and not "seguelmResults" as in the example you provided.

Comment: well no - I first let the user go to the uitableview called "seguelmResults" before he moves on to the details page and this is where the error happens. so the structure is -> uitableview -> uitableview -> details

Comment: When you say the uitableview called "segueImResults" you are referring to the segue, correct? Your explanation of your layout is very confusing. Do you have 2 UITabBars? Or do you have 1 UITabBar with 2 items?